# Weird tau greek letter

Tags: fonts, greek, letters

I have a Physics book in which the work done by a force is represented by the greek letter *tau*.

Thing is, it's a different form of *tau*, a form I've never seen before. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

(sorry about the low quality pic)

The greek tau found in LaTeX's default greek alphabet looks quite different. Is there any command in which I would generate such above form of *tau*?

(there's no mention of it in "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List", and I have already tried "Detexify" soft (which didn't give a good solution), only solutions given by the "duplicate" in discussion)

Comment: Could this be `\zeta`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: I've already tried using Detexify software. And the book says it's a Tau.

Comment: Any reference for the book?

Comment: @HenriMenke However, I think this question should not be closed. Detextify doesn't give an acceptable solution and searching in _The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List_ I have found only the symbol of my answer, which is not the best.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Asking for a symbol/font is actually off-topic here. There is https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com for such questions.  We just close it as duplicate because we cannot migrate there.

Comment: @egreg It's a Brazilian physics book: 
"Ferraro, Nicolau Gilberto; Ramalho Junior, Francisco; Soares, Paulo Toledo. Os Fundamentos da Física - Vol. 1"

Comment: Here's an extract from the book's page with the symbol:
http://tinyurl.com/weirdtau

Comment: @ItaloMarinho My impression is that they chose a weird symbol among the ones available. I'd simply go with `\tau` if that's the usual name for the object.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to. It's because as a teacher, I've always used this weird tau symbol; it looks clearer for the students, in my opinion. So that's why I wanted to migrate this into my publishings. But thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\textturntwo` from `tipx` packages looks similar to it, in my opinion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\textturntwo

$\text{\textturntwo}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is just the number 2 rotated by 180°.

Comment: But it really looks very similar to the provided picture in the question :)

Comment: @HenriMenke Probably that's the reason why they call it "turn two" :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Just sayin', because it is certainly not Greek.

Comment: @HenriMenke I haven't found a better ready-to-use symbol :)

Comment: Well, it's the best solution that has been given. It's actually pretty close to the original. Thanks a lot for the alternative!

Comment: @ItaloMarinho Thank you for accepting my answer! However, egreg asked you some reference for the book. Maybe, if you give him this info, he could find a better solution :)

Comment: @ItaloMarinho You're welcome! Egreg is a TeX genius,  if he can't find a better solution, no one else can :):):)

Comment: That terminal ball makes a big difference IMO -- without it this would look a lot less like a `2`

Comment: This is a great symbol to have for typesetting duodecimal base-12 numbers "ten" (`\textturntwo`) and "eleven" (`\textturnthree`). However I've noticed some incompatibility where `tipx` changes fonts in headings. See this question regarding the `exercises` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602947/make-exercises-package-compatible-with-kaobook

Comment: @Mathemanic: just to clarify. `tipx` doesn't change fonts in headings. The font size issue you saw is because incorrect grouping. The `tipa` (and hence `tipx`) packages does redefine `\;` , `\:`, `\!`, `\|`, and `\*` for special uses for the phonetic alphabet. I expect this being described in its documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for fixing the issue @WillieWong! :)